# Transferring from listview to listbox and updating SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, listview, listbox

I have a form that transfers data from `listview` to `listbox` with a SQL query. I have no errors, the SQL code is reading the query and transferring data from `listview` to `listbox` is working, but it seems my `SqlCommand` is not running/updating my `datagridview`. I don't know if this is the right place to put the `SqlCommand` - please help me resolve this.

```
for (int intCount = 0; intCount < listViewOrders.Items.Count; intCount++)
{
    listBoxInvoice.Items.Add(listViewOrders.Items[intCount].Text);
    listBoxInvoice.Items.Add("                              x" + listViewOrders.Items[intCount].SubItems[2].Text +
                             "                  @                " + listViewOrders.Items[intCount].SubItems[1].Text);

    connect.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblProducts SET productQuantity = productQuantity - " +
                            listViewOrders.Items[intCount].SubItems[2].Text + "WHERE productName = '" + listViewOrders.Items[intCount].Text + "'", connect);

    connect.Close();
}

dataGridProd.Update();
dataGridProd.Refresh();
```

Thank you in advance. Any type of response is appreciated.

Comment: do you have any errors during runtime?

Comment: @JericCruz no errors so far, but it’s not updating the productQuantity

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: You're just *defining* the `cmd` - but you're never **executing** (running) it ..... you need to use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` (before the `connect.Close()` call) to actually **run that code** .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a spacing in your query, specifically in `WHERE` clause.

[image]

So do it like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblProducts SET productQuantity = productQuantity - " + listViewOrders.Items[intCount].SubItems[2].Text + " WHERE productName = '" + listViewOrders.Items[intCount].Text + "'", connect);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

or if you are using C#6+ then use string interpolation.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand($@"UPDATE tblProducts SET productQuantity = productQuantity - {listViewOrders.Items[intCount].SubItems[2].Text} WHERE productName = '{listViewOrders.Items[intCount].Text}'", connect);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> Don't forget to execute it using `ExecuteNonQuery` since you are
>   updating a data.

And make sure `listViewOrders.Items[intCount].Text` has a value. You can add a break point to check it.

===============UPDATE================

> Much better if you use SQL parameters to avoid SQL injection.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblProducts SET productQuantity = productQuantity - @quantity WHERE productName = @productName", connect);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", listViewOrders.Items[intCount].SubItems[2].Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productName", listViewOrders.Items[intCount].Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: thank you very much. I just forgot the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: One more thing sir. How can I update the datagridview on a button? I’m using dataGridView.Refresh(); and Update(); but nothing works. Sir sa uulitin. Maraming salamat 

Comment: You can update first the data source that is bound to your datagrid and then do `dataGridProd.Refresh()`.